# Design Elements getting signed randomly

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

This morning my boss asked me if I was making changes in the Domino PNAB. I wasn't. I did make one change the day before. Well Designer is showing that I signed scores or hundreds of design elements in the address book, which I did NOT do, at least manually.

We have seen this on and off for years now, and always just ignored it (my boss would resign the design.

Has anyone else experienced this or know what could be the cause. I think I will probably have to open an PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few causes. Ones that come to mind are design refresh occurring, auto-refresh from source control ODP and replication from another source. The User Detail on the database may be informative (Database Properties, second tab, User Detail...), it may show when it occurred, which could clarify things.

Comment: Paul, I was research this and I may have an idea why its is happening. I have build automatically turned on. I bop between Xpages and Domino design all day long. I read (I think in your blog) that if you build then ALL Projects get built - does that include Domino Designer elements as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Build Automatically enabled (I don't), that *could* cause issues with signing, especially if any change is detected by different signers. Notes/Designer 8.5.3 IF2 should fix an issue where just opening an NSF can causing a signing change for Java classes, but that should be fixed. As Paul mentions, watching out for *any* potential changes to an app, such as automatic import from ODP, etc., should be watched for. I'm rather leery of leaving Build Automatically on or anything making a change without my explicit direction. I mention this since my company still has a surprising number of older client versions.

Kathy Brown's blog post on the subject ca. pre- 8.5.3 IF2:
http://www.runningnotes.net/index.php/2013/08/29/mystery-application-breakage/